# The gap between MapAt and ReplacePart for 2D data tables with headers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Consider a relational table derived from survey data, where each column (`"001-01"` ...) represents a responder and each row (`"MDQ1"`...) a survey question.

To help intuition, response data is represented graphically by color-scaled disks, but the underlying data matrix is just a table of integers and bordered by the aforementioned string metadata in the first row and column.

[image]

A small submatrix is given here:

```
  data = {{"ID", "MDQ1", "MDQ2", "MDQ3"}, {"001-01", 3, 2, 5}, {"002-01", 4, 1,
       5}, {"003-01", 2, 2, 5}}
```

Further, define a variable for the headers

```
ids = {"ID", "MDQ1", "MDQ2", "MDQ3"}
```

To clean this data, the response values for a subset of questions, for example `{"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}` must be transformed, for example, by the function `(6-#)&`

(Note: in the figure I highlighted `"MDQ1"` and `"MDQ5"` - that's just for illustration)

I would prefer to use `ReplacePart` but afaik, pattern matching can only be applied to position index and *not* to the data values - but in this case the metadata (headers) is part of the data.

The alternative for this task is `MapAt`, but it requires the intermediate generation of the positional index and barely readable code:

```
MapAt[If[NumericQ[#], 6 - #, #] &, data, 
 Flatten[Table[{i, First@First@Position[ids, #]}, {i, 2, 
      Length@data}] & /@ {"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}, 1]]
```

Is there a way to close the semantic gap between `MapAt` and `ReplacePart` and achieve more terse, more readable code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes, the simplest approach might not be all that unreadable after all. Double `Transpose` works fine here:

```
transform[data_, q_, fun_] := 
     Transpose[data] /. ({#, x__} :> {#, Sequence @@ fun[{x}]} & /@ q) // Transpose

transform[data, {"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}, 6 - # &]
(* {{"ID", "MDQ1", "MDQ2", "MDQ3"}, {"001-01", 3, 2, 1}, 
    {"002-01", 2, 1,1}, {"003-01", 4, 2, 1}} *)
```

Comment: I like the simplicity. IMO it would be even more readable to use `{id : Alternatives @@ q, x__} :> {id}~Join~fun@{x}` as the replacement rule.

Comment: @Simon or to Golf it:  `transform[data_, {q__}, 
  fun_] := (data\[Transpose] /. {id : q | _?0, x__} :> {id} ~Join~ 
      fun@{x})\[Transpose]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I love it. Especially the use of a pattern which will never match anything :-)  Could also use `q|q` there.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. Indeed you could, but you slow down the matching as every alternative is tried twice on expressions that don't match.  (EDIT: I realize I wrote "Golf" but I was actually seeking to make it practical, if a bit obfuscated.)

Answer (score 8):

I default to using `Part` in cases like this.  I like the fact that it can be used for in-place modification, *or* on a copy of the data.

I would also use either a list of replacement rules (optimized with `Dispatch` if it is long) or a `DownValues` hash table in place of searching with `Position` in each application.

With:

```
data = {{"ID", "MDQ1", "MDQ2", "MDQ3"},
        {"001-01", 3, 2, 5}, {"002-01", 4, 1, 5}, {"003-01", 2, 2, 5}};

idx = # -> #2[[1]] & ~MapIndexed~ data[[1]];
```

On a copy:

```
keyMap1[f_, dat_, key_] := Module[{x = dat},
   Scan[(x[[2 ;;, #]] = f /@ x[[2 ;;, #]]) &, key /. idx];
   x
 ]

keyMap1[6 - # &, data, {"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}]
```

> ```
> {{"ID", "MDQ1", "MDQ2", "MDQ3"},{"001-01", 3, 2, 1},{"002-01", 2, 1, 1},{"003-01", 4, 2, 1}}
> ```

In-place modification:

```
SetAttributes[keyMap2, HoldAll]

keyMap2[f_, dat_, key_] :=
  Scan[(dat[[2 ;;, #]] = f /@ dat[[2 ;;, #]]) &, key /. idx]

keyMap2[6 - # &, data, {"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}]

data
```

> ```
> {{"ID", "MDQ1", "MDQ2", "MDQ3"},{"001-01", 3, 2, 1},{"002-01", 2, 1, 1},{"003-01", 4, 2, 1}}
> ```

In either case if you have multiple tables you could add `idx` as a parameter or use `{"MDQ1", "MDQ3"} /. idx` (with the appropriate index) as an argument.

I chose to explicitly map `f` onto the column elements; this is more general, but it is not as fast as [using the `Listable` property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7925/121).  If you are willing to make sure that every function you use is listable then the method will perform better after replacing `f /@` with `f @`.

Alternatively you might consider bundling this information with the table itself in a container:

```
data2 = idxtab[data, idx];

keyMap3[f_, idxtab[dat_, index_], key_] :=
  Module[{x = dat},
    (x[[2 ;;, #]] = f /@ x[[2 ;;, #]]) & /@ (key /. index);
    x
  ]

keyMap3[6 - # &, data2, {"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}]
```

Comment: +1. I agree with the approach. Behind this particular question, I see a broader one, requesting a different and more mutable (relational) data model, similar to data frames in R, which Mathematica currently lacks. I would approach the problem in similar ways, since mutability is IMO inherent in the general question / problem I see here, if not this particular one.

Comment: Definately the way +1

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Position` initially to know where in each row to `MapAt`, then `Map` `MapAt` over the data:

```
transform[data_, q_, fun_] := 
  With[{i = Position[ids, s_ /; MemberQ[q, s]]}, MapAt[fun, #, i] & /@ data]
```

(usage stolen from R.M's answer)

Answer (score 2):

We can make OP's original approach just a little bit shorter:

```
MapAt[If[NumericQ[#], 6 - #, #] &, data, 
      Join @@ Tuples[{Range[2, Length[dat]], 
                      Flatten[Position[ids, #] & /@ {"MDQ1", "MDQ3"}]}]
```