# Can you label an array by variables or strings instead of integers?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to label an array by a variable instead of an integer? For example calling the array `I[i,j]` with `{i,j} = {x,y,z}` instead of `{i,j} = {1,2,3}`?

For example, I might want to label the components of the Inertia tensor by `I[x,x]`, `I[x,y]`.. instead of `I[1,1]`, `I[1,2]`..

Comment: I find this question opaque.  Could you please give a practical example of what you want?

Comment: `l[x,y]=34;l["s", j]=54` and now you index `l[x,y]`? Also, `x=1;y=2` and `l[[x,x]]` becomes `l[[1,1]]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I added an practical example. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: As you've been on stackexchange [awhile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1339914/djbunk?tab=accounts) now, I would suggest you learn how to correctly format your questions. For inline code, wrap them in grave marks (`). For block code, indent each line by 4 spaces, with a blank line preceding and following the code.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand.  What do you mean by *label*?  Are you trying to extract an element based on a particular tag, e.g. `v = {1, 2, 3}` and then you want `v[["x"]]` to return `2`? (Note the string `"x"` to illustrate an arbitrary tag.)  Or, is this a display issue of some kind?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - yes, that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @rcollyer - Sorry, I usually format things, but I didn't think it mattered in the context of a sentence. I'll be more careful next time. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Assuming that there is not a global mapping of tags to positions for all arrays or you are only doing this for one array you will need a way to identify a particular array for *Mathematica* to know which mapping to use.  Will the arrays *always* be assigned to and accessed by a symbol?  Please also see these related posts: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/the-gap-between-mapat-and-replacepart-for-2d-data-tables-with-headers/9279#9279), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/emulating-r-data-frame-getters-with-upvalues/9731#9731)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you just want something like this?

```
inertia = Array[\[CapitalIota] @@ {"x", "y", "z"}[[{##}]] &, {3, 3}];    
MatrixForm[inertia]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  I(\text{x},\text{x}) & I(\text{x},\text{y}) &
>    I(\text{x},\text{z}) \\
>  I(\text{y},\text{x}) & I(\text{y},\text{y}) &
>    I(\text{y},\text{z}) \\
>  I(\text{z},\text{x}) & I(\text{z},\text{y}) &
>    I(\text{z},\text{z}) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Here I used the Greek *I* to avoid confusion with the complex `I`, and made the text labels appear as strings in a list `{"x", "y", "z"}` whose parts are selected based on the position in the 2D `Array` over integers from `1` to `3`. This matrix `inertia` is now ready to be used for symbolic manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a data structure and some labels, which I will arrange for convenience this way:

```
data = Thread[{x, "charlie", y, z, "bob"} -> {5, 17, 24, 7, 1}]
```

The goal is to have a function, which, when called with `x` will give `5`, when called with `y` will give `24`, when called with `"bob"` will give `1`, etc. Here is one way to achieve such indexing:

```
y //.data
24

{x, "bob"} //. data
{5, 1}
```

This can be made into a function easily:

```
locate[x_] := x //. data
```

so that `locate[x]` is `5`, `locate[{"bob", z}]` is `{1, 7}`, etc.

Handling matrices or tensors of values can be done similarly. Set up the desired labels in `labelMat` and the corresponding values in `vals`. Then create the list of rules as in `data2`

```
labelMat = {{"I[x,x]", "I[x,y]"}, {"I[y,x]", "I[y,y]"}};
vals = {{1, 3}, {5, 7}};
data2 = Thread[Flatten[labelMat] -> Flatten[vals]];
```

This can then be applied to individual terms or lists of terms:

```
{"I[x,y]", "I[y,y]"} //. data2
{3,7}
```

Comment: For vectors, *much* better, and I'll retract my prior comment.  However it is not yet complete for arbitrary tensors.  I suspect this question will end up being a duplicate, though I'm waiting for certain clarifications from the OP.